# Heroku Not Receiving Seed Data from Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I deployed a Rails App to Heroku and the database migrated fine, except the db/seeds.rb file won't push to Heroku. I've tried running heroku run rake db:seed, as well as all the other solutions suggested online, but nothing is working. Heroku doesn't seem to have access to the seeds.rb file at all.

After running heroku run db:seed, nothing seems to happen of worth:

```
Running rake db:seed on ⬢ top5application... up, run.1885 (Free)
D, [2017-11-02T05:42:19.665233 #4] DEBUG -- :   
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.3ms)  SELECT 
"schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

The Heroku logs also don't seem to contain any useful information:

```
1d22032e7d7e fwd="69.201.160.131" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=4542 protocol=https
2017-11-02T05:13:34.409329+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-02T05:13:34.409232 #4]  INFO -- : [44ea0b33-64d7-4516-90d1-1d22032e7d7e] Started GET "/lists" for 69.201.160.131 at 2017-11-02 05:13:34 +0000
2017-11-02T05:13:34.410736+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-02T05:13:34.410667 #4]  INFO -- : [44ea0b33-64d7-4516-90d1-1d22032e7d7e] Processing by ListsController#index as HTML
2017-11-02T05:13:34.413696+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-11-02T05:13:34.413601 #4] DEBUG -- : [44ea0b33-64d7-4516-90d1-1d22032e7d7e]   [1m[36mList Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "lists".* FROM "lists" ORDER BY average_rating DESC[0m
2017-11-02T05:13:34.415282+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-02T05:13:34.415205 #4]  INFO -- : [44ea0b33-64d7-4516-90d1-1d22032e7d7e]   Rendering lists/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-11-02T05:13:34.417088+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-11-02T05:13:34.416900 #4] DEBUG -- : [44ea0b33-64d7-4516-90d1-1d22032e7d7e]   [1m[36mList Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "lists".* FROM "lists" ORDER BY "lists"."created_at" DESC[0m
2017-11-02T05:13:34.418866+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-11-02T05:13:34.418785 #4] DEBUG -- : [44ea0b33-64d7-4516-90d1-1d22032e7d7e]   [1m[36mTopic Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "topics".* FROM "topics"[0m
2017-11-02T05:13:34.419839+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-02T05:13:34.419757 #4]  INFO -- : [44ea0b33-64d7-4516-90d1-1d22032e7d7e]   Rendered lists/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.3ms)
2017-11-02T05:13:34.422316+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-11-02T05:13:34.422246 #4] DEBUG -- : [44ea0b33-64d7-4516-90d1-1d22032e7d7e]   [1m[36mUser Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2017-11-02T05:13:34.423714+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-02T05:13:34.423652 #4]  INFO -- : [44ea0b33-64d7-4516-90d1-1d22032e7d7e]   Rendered layouts/_logged_in.erb (0.8ms)
2017-11-02T05:13:34.423973+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-02T05:13:34.423915 #4]  INFO -- : [44ea0b33-64d7-4516-90d1-1d22032e7d7e] Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 7.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
```

I'd really appreciate any insight because this is very perplexing.

Comment: are you sure you committed the seed file? Does `heroku run cat db/seeds.rb` show the correct file contents?

Comment: I've committed the db to master and then reset the postgres db and re-migrated a few times, so i'm sure the seed file is committed, but when i run that command you gave me it just shows the initial seed file that comes with rails, and not the version i have with the seed data in it.

Comment: if it's not showing the correct file contents than i really think you haven't managed to push the latest version to heroku. Did you do `git push heroku master` lately? You can also check which commit it's at using `git ls-remote heroku`

Comment: of course you were right! some how i'd gotten by brain stuck into a pattern of running db:migrate and not pushing. thank you.